# Can position accuracy indicator be animated in here maps?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I am implementing a scenario where I am trying to animate map accuracy indicator surrounding the position indicator using here maps

It should animate like ripples along the route with position indicator

But could not find any interface in HereMaps Android SDK document
Can you help with the same ? !

[Ripple animated circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAJYt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What about using different MapCircles on the coordinates of the current position in different colors?
A MapCircle represents a type of MapObject in the shape of a circle with an assigned radius distance and a GeoCoordinate center. It can be created by calling the constructor MapCircle(double radius, GeoCoordinate center).

Comment: I have tried map Circles with different colours..it works. how do I animate it ? Like ripple animation for that circle